# TinyMCE 3 advanced theme to TinyMCE 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

When I initialize TinyMCE 3, I'm using this option:

```
theme : "advanced"
```

But I noticed this is not available anymore in TinyMCE 4, there is only the `modern` option.

Does anyone know if the advanced theme was ported to TinyMCE 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is looking at the css of the advanced theme in version 3 located at:

```
tiny_mce\themes\advanced\skins\default\ui.css
```

From that is possible to replicate part of it using the skin creator for version 4 located at http://skin.tinymce.com/.

A tedious task but quite painless with the skin creator.